# How to write text with line space to a CSV file?

Tags: javascript, csv, npm

I'm getting product descriptions in an object with strings.
I'd like to write the data to a CSV file so I can do some data analysis.

I need the data to be visually good looking so I can easily read it.
The thing is, all I get so far is a bunch of tight hard to read strings.

If you edit from excel you'll use Alt+Enter, which will create some space in the same row.
How do I write to the file with some line spaces, that doesn't create a new row in excel?

I found that:

1. `\n` is copied as test
2. `\r\n` is starting a new row instead only spacing the row

For example:

```
fs.appendFile(`./data/testCSV.csv`,  encodeURIComponent(element.name +'\r\n'+ element.description + '\r\n'+ element.short_description), function (err) {
 if (err) throw err;
});
```

Will give it in 3 separated rows

Here is an example of how I'd like it to look like:

[image: CSV example]

Also tried to find an NPM parser, but all of them create new lines as well.

Comment: Did you open the version created with Excel in a text editor, in order to find how the line breaks using `Alt` + `Enter` are encoded?

Comment: yes, it's just rapping it with " ". When I used an online View non-printable Unicode characters tool, have found this: CR LF between. But couldn't find how to use this info.

Comment: Btw. It's unnecessary to enclose the path, i.e. `\`./data/testCSV.csv\``, with backticks as it contains no  embedded expression(s) as per a Template Literal. Enclose the path in single or double quotes instead.

Answer (score 1):

To have multiline fields in a csv you need to enclose the field with quotes:

```
123,"multi 
line 
text",456
```

Quotes inside the fields have to be escaped with another quote:

```
123,"Samsung 
24"" 
monitor",456
```

Not sure if Excel will hanlde this right though.

Comment: True, but how do you add this in the JS string? i get the string as is, I can only splice and concatenate with some other string, using a script. I cant just press the Enter key.

Comment: @yoni349 You can just use `\n` or `\r\n`, but I wouldn't put that inside `encodeURIComponent()`.

Comment: that's just ending and starting a new row in the excel. i need it to space within the same cell/row.

Comment: @yoni349 You can create the following string for the above multiline field: `'"multi \nline \ntext"'`or `'"multi \n\nline \n\ntext"'` if you want empty lines in between.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Danny_ds.

This variable version works well:

```
 `"${x} \n ${y} \n\n ${z}"`
```

Comment: The spaces seem unnecessary and given the example in your question It should be: `\`"${element.name}\n${element.description}\n\n${element.short_description}"\``